# Trying to use dictionary comprehension to hold user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

The information users input is stored in a .txt file.

A function then reads the file and attempts to iterate through the info and creating a dictionary to hold the information.

So far my work has only been able to iterate over the first sequence of inputs.

```
dicti = {}
with open('cart.txt','r') as infile:
    content = infile.readlines()
    content = [x.strip() for x in content]
    keys = ['Item','Price','Quantity']
    findic = {}
    for x in content:
        dicti = {k:v for k,v in zip(keys,content)}
    print(dicti)
```

The output is : {'Item': 'milk', 'Price': '2.0', 'Quantity': '2'}

while the .txt shows info like

```
milk
2.0
2
egg
1.0
1
```

I seem to have gotten the first piece but I think I need help making this a nested dictionary to hold more items the user may input.

Comment: Please use the edit feature of Stackoverflow to update your question rather than commenting.

Comment: On each iteration of your `for` loop, you create a brand new `dicti`, overwriting the previous one.  Appending them to a list would be the simplest way to keep all of the dictionaries for later use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remember zip function always stops at lowest number of arguments.

below is another way
idea is to split by 3

```
r = []
keys = ['Item','Price','Quantity']
with open('car.txt', 'r') as infile:
    content = infile.readlines()
    for i in range(0, len(content), 3):
        r.append(dict(zip(keys, content[i:i+3])))

print(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
keys = ["Item", "Price", "Quantity"]
with open("items.txt", "r") as infile:
    result = [{}]
    values_count = 0
    for line in infile.readlines():
        print(result)
        if values_count == len(keys):  # we have run out of keys
            values_count = 0  # so reset to 0 
            result += [{}]. # and make a new dict
        result[-1][keys[values_count]] = line.strip(). # set the key:value on the last dict
        values_count += 1. # increment the values_count so we use the next key on the next loop

    print(result)
```

You want to have a list of dicts, right? You should use the expected `keys` during your loop to know when a new dict is needed or when to just update the existing last dict (`result[-1]`).

Comment: this worked but printed every step of adding a piece to the dict. thanks for the help cheers.